# R problem when using 'mediate' package: Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected

Tags: r, rename, analysis

all. I'm using the mediate package in R and have the following issue. My three variables are:

> ```
> X = condition (-1 or 1)
> M = arousal (1..5)
> Y = answer (0 or 1)
> ```

My code is:

> ```
> med.fit <- lm(arousal ~ condition, data=data)
> out.fit <- glm(answer ~ arousal, family = binomial, data=data) # binary outcome
>
> med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "condition", mediator = "arousal")
> ```

And I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in `[.data.frame`(y.data, , treat) : undefined columns selected
> ```

My guess is that this happens because the coefficient changes from **condition** to **condition1** in med.fit, because the predictor is categorical. I successfully renamed the coefficient using:

> ```
> names(med.fit$coefficients) <- sub("condition1", "condition", names(med.fit$coefficients))
> ```

... but I get the same error.

I'm new to R and was wondering whether someone might have the solution to this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO, @held.together.by.magic! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(data))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**: the second model was simply missing treatment (*condition*) as a covariate.

```
out.fit <- glm(answer ~ arousal + condition, data=data)
```